# Cannot connect to my containerized gRPC server

Tags: go, docker-compose, grpc, docker-network

I have a git repo with the given folder structure

```
grpc-repo
|---grpc-client (:8083)
|---grpc-server (:9000)
|---docker-compose.yml
|---Dockerfile
|---Dockerfile2
```

Now, these gRPC client-server project is running seamless normally.
But then, I need to dockerize this project.

Given below is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  client:
    container_name: grpc-client
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    networks:
      - my-network
  server:
    container_name: grpc-server
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile2
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

After dockerizing the project, I am easily able to connect to the gRPC client.. but the client is not able to connect to the gRPC server.

It says ...

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp :9000: connect: connection refused
```

This is how I am creating a connection to the server in my golang code

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(":9000", grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not connect: %s", err)
}
```

Can anyone help me with what am I doing wrong here ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access a gRPC running in a docker container from another container you have to use DNS resolution.

```
grpc.Dial("dns:///grpc-server:9000", grpc.WithInsecure())
```

where `grpc-server` is the container name you declared in `container_name: grpc-server`