# grpc client docker-compose to listen a port from grpc server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, grpc, grpc-java

2 file  GRPC Client and GRPC Server if i run it manual to my IDE its able to connect to the localhost:9090 and send data  while the GRPC Server is running in Docker.

But if i used docker-compose.yaml in GRPC CLIENT it wont listen to 9090.

2 file  GRPC Client and GRPC Server if i run it manual to my IDE its able to connect to the localhost:9090 and send data  while the GRPC Server is running in Docker.

But if i used docker-compose.yaml in GRPC CLIENT it wont listen to 9090.

```
//Client Service
@Service
public class ProductService   {
    
     private ManagedChannel channel;
     private  ProductServiceGrpc.ProductServiceStub productServiceStub;
     private ProductServiceGrpc.ProductServiceBlockingStub productServiceBlockingStub;

    private void initializeStub() {
        channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 9090).usePlaintext().build();
        productServiceBlockingStub = ProductServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
        productServiceStub = ProductServiceGrpc.newStub(channel);
    }
    

    

    
      public ProductService() {
            initializeStub();
        }
      
}
```

```
//Client side
//application.yaml

server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT:8094} 
  
grpc: 
  server:
    port: ${GRPC-SERVER-PORT:9099}
```

```
//GRPC Client
//Docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'


networks:
  default:
    name: product-poc-project-net
    external: true


services:
  cartgatewayservice:
    image: cartgatewayservice:latest
    container_name: cartgatewayservice
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9000:8094
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: 8094
      GRPC-SERVER-PORT: 9090
      GRPC-SERVER_HOST: cartservice
```

```
//GRPC Service
//Docker-compose.yaml

version: '3.8'


networks:
  default:
    name: product-poc-project-net
    external: true


services:

  cartservice:
    image: cartservice:latest
    container_name: cartservice
    depends_on:
      - cart-mysqldb
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    
    ports: 
      - "9090:9090"
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: cart-mysqldb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      GRPC-SERVER-PORT: 9090

  cart-mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: cart-mysqldb
    ports: 
      - "3307:3306"
    
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbpoc
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Comment: Try adding the client and server containers to the same user-defined network.  The default bridge network does not allow containers to address each other by name like you're trying to do.

Comment: @JoshBothun, they are in the same network `product-poc-project-net`.

Comment: i just fix it refrence link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70152887/cannot-connect-to-my-containerized-grpc-server

solution: change localhost to container_name that you try to connect

```
channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("cartservice", 9090).usePlaintext().build();
```

Answer (score 1):

i just fix it refrence link [Cannot connect to my containerized gRPC server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70152887/cannot-connect-to-my-containerized-grpc-server)

solution:
change localhost to container_name that you try to connect

```
channel= ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("cartservice",9090).usePlaintext().build();
```